# creating a task that always run as a final cleanup step?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle build file that has tasks that start docker containers for integration testing.

I would like to create a task that always runs once as a final cleanup step to stop the docker containers, regardless of whether previous tasks were successful or failed.

Is this possible in gradle?  How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a cleanup task at the end and use the `taskGraph` to do the cleanup when an other task fails:

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
    if (state.failure) {
        doCleanup
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be executing when my build fails with: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

Comment: That's odd because in 58.6.4 at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html their example throws an exception which they are able to catch...

Comment: I created a new build file from example in 58.6.4 and it works for me.  Now I need to find out why it isn't working on my build file :(